# Shopify all blog articles on one blog template

Tags: shopify

I'm working on setting up a blog template page that has all blog articles on it in chronological order. I've been working my way one step at a time to make sure it is all working but from what I have read that the
`{% for blog in blogs %}<h1>{{ blog.title }}</h1>{% endfor %}`
should be returning the blog.title of all the blogs which it is not. I doesn't even seem as if the loop is running. Is there something that I am missing here with the result being what is stated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
{% for link in linklists.blogs.links %}
  {% assign blog = link.object %}
  {% for article in blog.articles %}
    <h2><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h2>
  {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Welcome, glad I could help